# Why can't I use $session_start()?

Tags: php, session

I got this error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: session_start in C:\wamp\www\check.php on line 3
```

It says undefined variable on line 3, but here's line 3.

```
$session_start();
```

Why is this happening? Isn't session_start predefined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) is a function.

`$session_start` would be a variable if you defined it. The error message you're reading is simply telling you that the variable that you're trying to call as a function doesn't exist as such.

Answer (score 2):

`session_start()`

It's not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

`session_start()` is not a variable, but a function. You do not need the dollar sign.  Change it to

```
session_start()
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's just `session_start()` with no $. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).