# file upload return to upload html page

Tags: php, html, session, upload

I'm looking to return to the previous page after a file upload and have "file uploaded successfully" on the upload page.

In upload.php at the top I have placed

```
sesssion_start();
```

And at the end of the file upload script I have placed

```
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = TRUE;
header("Location: stream.php");
```

Now I know i need to put some code into the html document but unsure what needs to go in. Below is my html form script

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="90000000" />
 Select video to upload:
Please choose a file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

I know it is going to be something similar to this but unsure how or where I would place it.

```
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['upload_success']) && $_SESSION['upload_success']) {
 echo "File uploaded successfully";
 }
```

If someone could walk me through adding the HTML code into the correct place I will be very greatful

After the comments i amend my php code to look like this.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
sesssion_start();
$target_path = "upload/";
$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] );
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] , $target))
{ 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ). " has been      uploaded"; 
  } 
 else {
   echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    }
   $_SESSION['upload_success'] = TRUE;
   header("Location: stream.php");
   exit();
```

And the syntax inside the stream.php to:

```
    <?phpsession_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['upload_success']) && $_SESSION['upload_success']) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully";
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['upload_success']) && $_SESSION['upload_success'] == TRUE)` try that, if that's what the question is about.

Comment: @Markjose I think you're on the right track. Try that and report what happens.

Comment: However, you can't use echo and header at the same time, so you'll need to remove the echo if it's inside the same file as the header you want to use. That is called "outputting before header".

Comment: @Fred-ii- would i add that under `<input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> ' ? =>in php tags ?

Comment: It looks like the header is in upload.php and the upload html form is in stream.php.

Comment: Either add the success code above or below the html form on stream.php.  Your preference really.  My question here is, what if the upload is not successful?  Do you not want a message that says, "file upload failed?"  If the upload fails is there some sort of exit() or die() in the upload.php file that we can't see?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17847344/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22490864

Comment: @Unipartisandev Wouldn't the command only work if the upload was successful ? and if unsuccessful not go back to the original page ?

Comment: Any success with the links I gave you?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have sat here trying to understand the function but i just don't. I had inserted the code. but got a fatal error, am going to update the information above now.  please bare in mind my PHP skills are very limited.

Comment: `sesssion_start();` typo. One "s" too many,. Plus, make sure there's no spaces before `<?php` or HTML or any type of output.

Comment: Ok, corrected the typo ( appolgies) however apache is  returning the following errors. 


`Notice: Undefined variable: session_start in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 2`

`Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 2`

Comment: Update your question/code with actuals. This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/9399700/ outlines the same error issue, so something is causing this that you may not be showing us.

Comment: Ok, I had an unnecessary $ hence why it was looking for a variable. That worked but never outputted any information to the main page. In the session in the stream.php would I have to link it to upload.php ?

Comment: I've posted something for you below. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: So, did you try my answer? It's simple, and it works. If not, I'll just delete it if it's not to serve anyone's purpose.

Comment: Will give it a go now Fred -ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota: You also cannot use echo and header together because that would considered as outputting before header, so we'll just use a session array as the message and the header to redirect to "upload_form.php", then show the respective message on that page afterwards.

Use `session_destroy()` also to destroy any previous sessions.

**Sidenote:** Use two seperate files.

HTML form: call this "`upload_form.php`"

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<form action="stream.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="90000000" />
Select video to upload:
Please choose a file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
 </form>

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['upload_success'])){
    echo $_SESSION['upload_success'];
}

else{
    echo "Please select a file.";
}

?>
```

PHP (file 2): call this "`stream.php`"

```
<?php 
session_start();

$target_path = "upload/";
$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] );

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] , $target))
{
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File successfully uploaded.";
header("Location: upload_form.php");
exit;
  } 

 else {
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";

header("Location: upload_form.php");
exit;
    }
```

---

**Edit:**

Modify and add the following after `if(move_uploaded_file...`

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){
   $target_path = "upload/";
   $target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you should remove session['upload_success'] with unset function after you do echo success message.
try

```
 unset( $_SESSION['upload_success'])
```

in stream.php right after

```
 echo "File uploaded successfully";
```

update :
if you want to work all these on a single page, You can simply do it like below:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['upload_success']) and $_SESSION['upload_session'])
   {
//echo success message
//remove session
}
if(isset($_POST['file'])){
//upload process , if it was successfull make seesion true...

}
else {

//show form

}
```

Comment: Ok amended the code however this had no impact.



`<?phpsession_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['upload_success'])){
  echo "File uploaded successfully"unset( $_SESSION['upload_success']);
  }
 ?>`

Comment: The impact can be seen when your upload is successfull and session is created and then you echo a message , but afterward even your code doesnt work you still have success message...

Comment: I'm now confused as no message is currently being displayed

Answer (score 0):

Placing

```
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = TRUE;
header("Location: stream.php");
```

At the end, I believe, would set true no matter what actually happened with the file's upload the reason being, there is not a condition being checked.

Unless the script has an exit command when it fails, it will eventually get to the part where it says: "Set the upload success as true and then go to stream.php" rather than saying, "If the upload is successful, set the upload success as true and then go to stream.php"

I would try:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

if($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] == 0)//In other words, if no file was selected.
    {
    $_SESSION['upload_success'] = 4;//File wasn't selected
    header("Location: stream.php");
    exit();
    }   

if(!file_exists('upload/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])))
    {       
    $_SESSION['upload_success'] = (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],'upload/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])) ? 1 : 2);
    }
elseif(file_exists('upload/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])))
    {
    $_SESSION['upload_success'] = 3;
    }

header("Location: stream.php");
exit(); 
?>
```

Now in stream.php where you have your if statement that displays the message do this instead:

```
<?php
session_start();

switch (@$_SESSION['upload_success']) {
    case 1:
        echo "File uploaded successfully";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "A file with that name already exists!";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "You must select a file to upload!";
        break;
}
unset($_SESSION['upload_success']);
 ?>//So if you reload stream.php yet another time no messages will be displayed again for no reason. ie. none of the cases will match an unset variable.
```

Last, you cannot echo (or do any type of output meant to be viewed by a user) before you `header(Location: "somepage.php");`

The page will switch before the user can read the output.

The way your code is currently written in your question you could have the following happen:

1. The server echos "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file", which will never be seen by the user.
2. $_SESSION['upload_success'] is then set to TRUE, which is obviously not in agreement with #1.
3. It then sends the user to stream.php where a success message is
   displayed.

An alternate, lazier way with less useful scenario descriptions to also fix your problem would be to do this instead (in upload.php):

```
else 
    {
    die("Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."); 
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok tried it got a syntax error but can't see the fault anywhere on line 6

`syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 6,`


Line 6 



`if(!file_exists('$target_path' . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']*))`

Comment: I have cleaned out some mistakes. See that *?  That wasn't supposed to be there.  That was added by Stack's italicizing function I was trying to italicize the path...  I also don't think you should have ' around $target_path.  I also didn't have basename() in place either.  I fixed all of those problems on my end at this point. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try

    `if(!file_exists($target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])))`

Comment: The else is unxpected according to apache logs. but that is the only issue.

Comment: Okay, I found out what I did wrong.  Change

`basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))) ? 1 : 0;`

to

`basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])) ? 1 : 0);

Comment: `error:  syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.0.110/stream.php`


IT is written the as on your post above is there a bracket or similar missing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72803/discussion-between-unipartisandev-and-markjose).

Comment: Ok, the process completed without any errors and the file uploaded, however nothing displayed on screen to notify the user of this. 
My php script after the form 


`<?phpsession_start();
switch ($_SESSION['upload_success']) {
    case 1:
        echo "File uploaded successfully";
        break;
    case 0:
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        break;
    case "filenameexists":
        echo "A file with that name already exists!";
        break;
}
unset($_SESSION['upload_success']);
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, you could use Ravi Kusuma's [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) or an AJAX solution to do this.

Another alternative, though, to those proposed above is to programmatically construct / output an HTML form with some javascript, and get it to POST a message to `stream.php`:

> CAVEAT: I haven't tried this myself, but I can't think why it wouldn't work. Would someone please confirm my sanity? ***-- Tested it myself: it works.***

```
<?php
    //upload.php

    //Do file upload stuff, then:

    $out = '
        <form id="frmUpOkay" action="stream.php" method="post">
            <input name="upMsg" value="Upload Successful" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#frmUpOkay").submit();
            });
        </script>
    ';
    echo $out;
?>
```

**You must also add this bit to the top of the `stream.php` file:**

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['upMsg']) && isset($_POST['upMsg']) != '' ){
        $upMsg = $_POST['upMsg']; //you should sanitize this input
    }else{
        $upMsg = '';
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Your normal website content is here.<br>
        <br>
        Upload message: <?php echo $upMsg; ?> <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notes:

Above code uses jQuery, so you would need the jQuery library included on your `upload.php` page *(as shown above).*